# Multiple instances of YouTube player inside loop

Tags: javascript, youtube, ytplayer

I have the following code, which works - but the part I can't figure out is how to grab the index in the onReady event. The result is 2,2 instead of 0,1 which I would expect - why?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/liquidvisual/pen/WzgMyZ?editors=1011)

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var players = [];
var playerEl = document.querySelectorAll('.ytplayer');

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
     for (var i = 0; i < playerEl.length; i++) {

         players[i] = new YT.Player(playerEl[i], {
             events: {
                 'onReady': () => { console.log('index: '+i) } // why doesn't this return 0,1 ??
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

```html
<iframe class="video ytplayer" width="100%" height="390" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4?controls=0&t=31s&loop=1&playlist=ScMzIvxBSi4&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe class="video ytplayer" width="100%" height="390" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iGpuQ0ioPrM?controls=0&t=31s&loop=1&playlist=iGpuQ0ioPrM&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the following code. The mistake I was making was I was trying to store a variable inside an event. The event is async and doesn't know that it's inside a loop - at least I think that's it, please correct me if I'm wrong.

[Codepen working](https://codepen.io/liquidvisual/pen/WzgMyZ?editors=1011)

```
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
     document.querySelectorAll('.ytplayer').forEach((item) => {
         new YT.Player(item, {
             events: {
                 'onReady': (event) => {
                     event.target.playVideo();
                     event.target.mute();
                 }
             }
         })
     })
}
```